# Replace empty element in a list using sapply

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have two lists. The first one has an empty element. I'd like to replace that empty element with the first vector of the third list element of another list.

```
l1 <- list(a=1:3,b=4:9,c="")
l2 <- list(aa=11:13,bb=14:19,cc=data.frame(matrix(100:103,ncol=2)))

l1[sapply(l1, `[[`, 1)==""] <- l2[[3]][[1]]
```

Using `sapply`, I can identify which elements are empty. However, when I try to assign a vector to this empty element: I get this error message:

> Warning message: In l1[sapply(l1, `[[`, 1) == ""] <- l2[[3]][[1]] :
>   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

This is only a warning, but the result I get is not the one I want. This is the l1 I get:

```
> l1
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

$c
[1] 100
```

This is what I need (two elements in $c):

```
> l1
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

$c
[1] 100 101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-hand side should be a list, since you're replacing a list element. So you want that to be

```
... <- list(l2[[3]][[1]])
```

In addition, you might consider using `!nzchar(l1)` in place of `sapply(...) == ""`.  It might be more efficient.  The final expression would be:

```
l1[!nzchar(l1)] <- list(l2[[3]][[1]])
```

giving the updated `l1`:

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

$c
[1] 100 101
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `l2[[3]][1]` on the right hand side (single `[` not `[[`)

Comment: True for this example. However, if the rhs is not already a list (like if it were `1:5`), it would need to be made into one.